# How to display a form field whose role is of enum datatype and is stored as integer in the database. The user can't change the role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My profile role is created and when the user logs in the profile controller's edit action view will be displayed. I want to show the role that is assigned to user in the edit action and the user cannot change the role. My `edit.html.erb` file is given as:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <h3>Profile</h3>
    <%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
                <%= f.email_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"%>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
                <%= f.password_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :role %><br />
                <%= f.select(:role, [['User', 'user'], ['Vip', 'vip'], ['Admin', 'admin']]) %>
            </div>

            <div class="actions form-group">
                <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
            </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show your user model?

Comment: Sure. I have used devise for user.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible way is just to use [`String#humanize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-humanize) from ActiveSupport.

> Capitalizes the first word, turns underscores into spaces, and (by
>   default)strips a trailing '_id' if present. Like titleize, this is
>   meant for creating pretty output.

```
irb(main):008:0> roles.roles.keys.map(&:humanize)
=> ["User", "Vip", "Admin"]
irb(main):009:0> Profile.new(role: :admin).role.humanize
=> "Admin"
```

`Profile.roles` gives us the hash mapping for the Enum.

You can use this to generate the select tag with:

```
<%= form.select :role, Profile.roles.keys.map{|k| [k.humanize, k] } %>
```

You can get "vip".humanize to return "VIP" by setting up an inflection:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'VIP'
end
```

This may require restarting your Rails server before it kicks in.

### Using the I18n module

But if you want a more flexible solution that lets you set the mappings yourself (and works with translations) use the [I18n module](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html):

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      profile:
        roles:
          user: 'User'
          vip: 'Very Important Person'
          admin: 'Admin'

# app/helpers/users_helper.rb
module UsersHelper
  def translate_role(role)
    I18n.t("activerecord.attributes.user.roles.#{ role }", default: role.humanize)
  end

  def role_options
    Profile.roles.keys.map{|k| [translate_role(k), k] }
  end
end
```

You would then display the users role by:

```
<%= translate_role(@user.role) %>
```

And you can setup the form input as:

```
<%= form.select :role, role_options %>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @max. I solved my problem by creating a hash in the same model in which I created the enum and then iterated over the hash whose value is the key to the enum roles which in turn sets my enum value.

Comment: I would still go with the `I18n` solution over that since display is not a model concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper method, For example in the `application_helper.rb` you can make a method like this:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def profile_role(profile)
    # Perform your logic
    # if you are using as_enum gem for example
    Profile.roles.select{|symbol_role,integer_rep| integer_rep == profile.role}.keys.first.to_s
    # of course there could be much better way to get the string.
  end
end
```

Then in your view, If user should not be able to change it, there is no need to make it as drop-down list:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
<h3>Profile</h3>
<%= form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"%>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :role %><br />
            <%= text_field_tag 'role', profile_role(@profile), disabled: true %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your profile_role method is creative but pointless as you can just call `#role` on the instance to get the value of the enum column (as a string). `Profile.new(role: :admin).role == 'admin'`.

Comment: Ahaa, I'm using old rails I didn't know that this does exists in ActiveRecord, Good and new information, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just show it as regular text, e.g.:

```
...

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :last_name %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>

        <p>
            Role:<br />
            <%= @profile.role %>
        </div>

        <div class="actions form-group">
            <%= f.submit "Submit", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>

...
```